# How to send a message without @ing the sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How do I send a message without pinging the sender in discord? I've got:

```
msg.reply(':smirk_cat:');
```

Which sends `@sender, :smirk_cat:`,
but what I want is just `:smirk cat:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
msg.channel.send(<message>)
```

The `msg.reply()` function replies the user by pinging them and then sending the message after the ping in the same message. For more info, read their official documentations here:

- [Docs on `message.reply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply)
- [Docs on `message.channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)
- [Guide on `message.reply()`](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#mentions)

To simply answer your question, use this instead:

```js
msg.channel.send(':smirk_cat:');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can do `msg.channel.send(YOUR_MESSAGE)`

In your case, it would be `msg.channel.send(':smirk_cat:')`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```js
message.channel.send()
```

---

[`channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel) is a property of the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object; it refers to the [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) the message was sent in. From there, we use the [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) the method, which will send a message to the channel it was called on. So, `message.channel.send()` will simply send a message to the channel that the *original* message was sent in.

[image: example]

---

You can also use this feature to send messages to other specific channels!

```js
// get a channel by it's id, then send a message to it
message.client.channels.cache.get('<Channel ID>').send();

// get a channel by its name (or any other property), then send a message to it
message.client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'general').send();
```